# Как заполнить матрицу единицами по координатам указанным в ключах словаря?

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте,есть словарь где ключи это координаты точек в матрице и значения ключей это значения точек в данных координатах и есть матрица заполненная нулями, 
 как можно по этим координатам указанным в ключах, на этой матрице расставить единицы? пробовал через numpy создавать эту матрицу и заполнять через получение ключей словаря, но похоже что то делаю не так.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, чтобы мы могли посмотреть, что именно вы делаете не так.

Comment: @Александр

import numpy as np

a1 = {(0, 0): 0.1, (1, 0): 0.2, (1, 1): 0.3, (3, 1): 0.1, (3, 2): 0.3}

m = np.zeros((7,8))
a1=a1.keys()
x=list(a1)
m[x]=1
print(x1)
как я понял значения должны быть целыми числами, но у меня не получается их перевести, наверно из за того что у меня список из кортежей получается

Comment: @Александр а всё кажется разобрался